# Magento 2 : Add custom tabs to product details page

Tags: magento2, product, tabs

How to show information `(Shipping rates,Report an issue,Questions and Returns)` in product details page tabs.It shows only Details,More information tabs.

Is there any back-end configuration available to add custom tabs with custom information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  can add Custom tab with product/custom information, this may not be possible by admin configuration.

You need to create a custom module by following below steps.assume you know how to  create a module, as i am not adding entire structure.

app\code\Vendor\Module\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
      <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
          <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Customtab" name="example.tab" template="Vendor_Module::customtab.phtml" group="detailed_info">
              <arguments>
                  <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Your Title</argument>
              </arguments>
          </block>
      </referenceBlock>
   </body>
</page>
```

Create a template app\code\Vendor\Module\view\frontend\templates\customtab.phtml

```
<h1>My custom tab info</h1>
```

Create a block and render the required details.

Remove the cache and check the new tab in details page.

Comment: In catalog_product_view.xml page whatever i want the tabs are there.How to enable it

Comment: How can I add more than one tabs in `catalog_product_view.xml`?

Comment: Hi @Omer, have u got any solution for adding two tabs?